# Is the recent documents in RibbonApplication Menu a Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control

I am trying to replicate the style and function of the **Ribbon Control** of WordPad.

In the `RibbonApplicationMenu`, there is a MRU list showing recent document's file name. When I click on file name, it will have style changes and open the document.

What is the control that houses the file name "test1"? Is it a RibbonButton? A ListBox? A RibbonTextBox? Anyone knows?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is up to you whatever you want to hold inside that area

Try out this code which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881617/how-to-add-header-to-ms-ribbons-application-menu/6882106#6882106). Hope it will clear things

```
 <Ribbon:Ribbon Grid.Row="0">
            <Ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
                    <Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                        <Grid MinHeight="500">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                <StackPanel  
                                        Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Foreground="DarkBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Hello World"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ListBox Grid.Row="1">
                                <ListBoxItem>List Box Item 1</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>List Box Item 2</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>List Box Item 3</ListBoxItem>
                                <ListBoxItem>List Box Item 4</ListBoxItem>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                    <Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"   ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"/>
                    <Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"   ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"/>
                    <Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"   ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"/>
                </Ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>

            </Ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>


        </Ribbon:Ribbon>
```

Comment: thank you. But what's inside is a RibbonControl because it inherits RibbonControl styles (Yellow background etc.), so it's not a ListBox, so my concern is what kind of Control that is available in .NET. Or is that something I have to write from scratch.

Comment: You can explore the Ribbon control, It's source code is available at http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview